# Statelessly paginate sorted queries

Tags: sql, rest, sorting, pagination, stateless

I am writing an API for a web app. I'd like to paginate results if the row on a table exceed some value. However I'd also like to allow clients to filter and sort results.

I know how to correctly paginate data using keyset pagination. However, it appears to me, keyset pagination is broken once you sort the results- since now the indexes are not in order. I don't want to use limit offset pagination.

I have read that a way to achieve what I want is to use database cursors. However I'd need the session to be sticky for that.

I also thought of storing the result on a temporary table and give it a unique name, if the user sends that same name back query data from that table instead. The problem with this is I'd have to use some timeout to delete the table, which might lead to some 404s if the client requests the next page after the timeout (can be bad for a client's UX).

So the question is as follows:
Is there a widely accepted way to achieve this, that is also stateless? If there isn't a stateless way, what is the most scalable way to achieve this? and preferably that is also not so messy.

If it helps, I'm using Swift, Vapor 3 (without Fluent ORM), and PostgreSQL.

And finally, am I missing something obvious?